# ParameterOverride in Unity for parameterized constructor c#

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am using version 1.2.0.0 of Microsoft.Practices.Unity and i want to resolve dependency for a parameterized constructor which takes two arguments. I am not able to use ParameterOverride, error says missing assembly. How can i solve this?

Comment: Unity 1.2? Holy crap! That version is **more than 8 years old!!!**.

Comment: I'd agree with @Steven; unless you have a freakishly good reason to stick with that version, upgrade, retry, and we'd gladly help you!

Comment: I don't think anyone here on SO remembers what the API of 1.2 looks like. Upgrade to the latest version and you have a chance of getting some help.

Comment: Cant help it, working with old code :D will upgrade